# How to upload multiple selected file with progress indicator in asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In brief, I am trying to POST the IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> from view to controller action.
And then start uploading process while notifying to user which file (file_name) in being uploaded.
sample code will be more appreciated.

Please help me..........
THANKS in advance

Comment: did you have a look at JS libraries which provide such features or do you expect to get everything from here?

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) is an excellent library to upload multiple files and inform the user with the uploading progress.

See the MVC implementation [here](https://github.com/maxpavlov/jQuery-File-Upload.MVC3)